# Manually installing Intellij azure-toolkit-for-intellij.jar contains invalid plugin descriptor

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I'm trying to manually install Azure toolkit for intellij but I'm getting an error:

```
3:52 pm Plugin error: File 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\plugins\azure-toolkit-for-intellij\lib\azure-toolkit-for-intellij.jar' contains invalid plugin descriptor
```

Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Go to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8053-azure-toolkit-for-intellij/versions and download the plugin
2. Unzip file from step 1 and manually drop it into intellij plugins folder

   C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\plugins
3. Restart intellij.
4. Observe error.
   [image]

I'm keen to know what I'm doing wrong. I can't install the plugin from inside the IDE because nothing is coming back in my marketplace window (likely because of my internet proxy settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin has invalid plugin xml descriptor file. Reported [the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/5825) to the plugin vendor.

Comment: Thank you. Any interim work around for that empty value in the config-file attribute? Or is that too of a plug-in provider specific question to ask here?

Comment: Spent a lot of time mucking around with the jar deleting line reported in the bug. I got a little bit further but the end result was a corrupted plugin